# Raspberry Pi, lost /dev/ttyUSB0 when plugged in second FTDI cable

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspbian

I had a RPi setup with 1 FTDI cable. I was able to use `/dev/ttyUSB0` in code without issues

When I plugged in a second FTDI cable, with the same vendor and product ID, `/dev/ttyUSB1` never showed up, instead I lost `/dev/ttyUSB0`

`lsusb` shows that both devices are enumerated correctly.

Now, even when I plug in just one FTDI cable, `/dev/ttyUSB0` still does not show up!

How can I get back the ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1?

Here is the output from `dir /dev` `lsusb` and `dmesg`

Thanks,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dir /dev
autofs           hwrng    loop6               null   ram2     serial1  tty13  tty23  tty33  tty43  tty53  tty63      vc-mem  vcsa3
block            initctl  loop7               ptmx   ram3     shm      tty14  tty24  tty34  tty44  tty54  tty7       vcs     vcsa4
bus              input    loop-control        pts    ram4     stderr   tty15  tty25  tty35  tty45  tty55  tty8       vcs1    vcsa5
cachefiles       kmsg     mem                 ram0   ram5     stdin    tty16  tty26  tty36  tty46  tty56  tty9       vcs2    vcsa6
char             log      memory_bandwidth    ram1   ram6     stdout   tty17  tty27  tty37  tty47  tty57  ttyAMA0    vcs3    vcsm
console          loop0    mmcblk0             ram10  ram7     tty      tty18  tty28  tty38  tty48  tty58  ttyprintk  vcs4    xconsole
cpu_dma_latency  loop1    mmcblk0p1           ram11  ram8     tty0     tty19  tty29  tty39  tty49  tty59  ttyS0      vcs5    zero
disk             loop2    mmcblk0p2           ram12  ram9     tty1     tty2   tty3   tty4   tty5   tty6   urandom    vcs6
fb0              loop3    mqueue              ram13  random   tty10    tty20  tty30  tty40  tty50  tty60  vc-cma     vcsa
fd               loop4    network_latency     ram14  raw      tty11    tty21  tty31  tty41  tty51  tty61  vchiq      vcsa1
full             loop5    network_throughput  ram15  serial0  tty12    tty22  tty32  tty42  tty52  tty62  vcio       vcsa2
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

…. dmesg
[  208.091689] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[  208.219273] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[  208.219296] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  208.219309] usb 1-1.5: Product: FT232R USB UART
[  208.219322] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  208.219334] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: A5052N9Z
```

Comment: Try using the `fdisk` command.  Do a `fdisk -l` and it should list all the connected devices and you can get the name from there.  Then you should be able to mount it.  I'm not sure `lsusb` will give the correct names.

Answer (score 0):

Your udev rule should control device node creation, try [this one](https://github.com/RishiGupta12/SerialPundit/blob/master/tools-and-utilities/99-sp-ftdi-d2xx.rules).